# Get HTML element with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form which has an *input text* and *select* this is using the `Selectize.js`. I want to access the element entered in the input and the select via *$scope* and the attribute *ng-Model*, I can't do this so I sent the variables parameter to my function. But when I try access `agencia` and `nome` I get a null. Can anyone help me to access this elements?

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h4>Contatos</h4>
    <div ng-repeat="contato in contatos" class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Nome:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contato.nome">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Ag&ecirc;ncia</h4>
            <div class="control-group">
                <select ng-model="contato.agencia" ng-options="agencia.nome for agencia in listaAgencias" class="demo-default" selectize>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" ng-click="novoContato(contato.nome, contato.agencia)">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="excluirContato()"
                ng-disabled="contatosVazio()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.novoContato = function (nome, agencia) {
    try{
        //Here I have a undefined   undefined
        alert(nome + '\t' + agencia);
    }catch(err){
        alert(err);
    }
    $scope.contatos.push({
        nome: nome,
        agencia: agencia
    })
    $scope.contatos.push({
        nome: "",
        agencia: ""
    });
    agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
        var embedded = data._embedded;
        $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
};
```

Comment: Why can't you use ng-model and get the data from $scope instead of passing it to the novoContato function?

Comment: I have something like a Type Error $scope.contato is undefined

Comment: ah yes, sorry I missed the fact that contato it is declared in ng-repeat

Comment: Please tell me your error details is `contato` is not defined? or `contatos` is not defined?

Comment: try passing the whole object as one argument, then use what is needed inside function. In general this is preferred since you have the object reference available. As far as any problems with the `<select>` would need to know more about the `selectize` directive

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't know what is your problem. but I can tell you some issues by your code

---

- I think you got this error **`$scope.contatosis is undefined`**

If yes, please declare the empty `$scope.contatos=[];` array in the top of your function

Look like

```
$scope.novoContato = function (nome, agencia) {
$scope.contatos=[];
// then do your code
}
```

---

- Why you pass the `nome, agencia` parameter to your function?

Simply you don't need pass these value to your function, because you can get his values from `$scope.contato` object

look like

```
$scope.novoContato = function () {// no parms
       $scope.contatos=[];        
        try{         
          alert($scope.contato.nome + '\t' + $scope.contato.agencia);// get those values from $scope object
        }catch(err){
          alert(err);
        }

        $scope.contatos.push({
          nome: $scope.contato.nome,
          agencia: $scope.contato.agencia
        });

        $scope.contatos.push({
             nome: "",
             agencia: ""
        });
        agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
            var embedded = data._embedded;
            $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
        }).catch(function (error) {
            alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    };
```

- Also the `ng-click`  should look like **`ng-click="novoContato()"`**